# Branch prediction in quantum algorithms

Tags: reference-request, quantum-computing

Are there any good examples of branching efficiency / prediction in quantum algorihms? Specifically suppose I have a set of CNOT gates one after the other that have the control line on the same line as the output of the CNOT gate?

Comment: I am not sure if this question makes sense in a circuit model. In particular, in quantum computing it is not always obvious what the control line and output line of something like a CNOT gate is. Throw a couple of Hadamards before and after the CNOT and suddenly the control and output have swapped. The only related concept I can think of is looking at the amount of entanglement generated by your circuit... but maybe others know more on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Artem, but perhaps [this paper](http://ics.org.ru/doc?pdf=1254&dir=e) on a quantum circuit model for constructing conditional statements may be of some relevance to what you are trying to figure out.

Comment: Can you please add the title of the paper, or update the link? It's broken, and without the name, the answer is basically void. Thank you.